# Iteration cycles of Z_n weights in path graphs: Why cycles of length 182 for a 6-node path?

Tags: gr.group-theory, graph-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, cycles

Assign to the $n$ nodes of a path graph vertex weights
forming a permutation of $(0,\ldots,n{-}1)$.
Now iterate the following update repeatedly:
Each node sums the weights of its neighbors, and that node's
weight is replaced (in the next iteration) by the sum $\bmod n$.
Here is the start of an example for $n=4$:

---

[image: Path4]


<sup>The leftmost node just copies the $1$ of its neighbor.


The 2nd node from the left is replaced with $(3+0) \bmod 4$.</sup>

---

Continuing, we fall into a cycle of length $6$:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 3 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\
 1 & 3 & 3 & 0 \\
 3 & 0 & 3 & 3 \\
 0 & 2 & 3 & 3 \\
 2 & 3 & 1 & 3 \\
 3 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
 3 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
With a different starting permutation, the cycle length can be $3$:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 \\
 3 & 3 & 3 & 1 \\
 3 & 2 & 0 & 3 \\
 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Similarly, for $n=5$, cycles of length $2$ and $8$ occur.
But I was surprised to find that for $n=6$,
for each of the $6!$ starting permutations,
the process always results in a cycle of length exactly $182$.

> ***Q***. What explains cycles of length $182$ for paths of $6$ nodes?

More generally, what explains the cycle lengths for different $n$?
Here are the cycle lengths I've explored so far, verified by
exhaustive search up to $n=9$.
See Moritz Firsching's comments and postings for data beyond my calculations.
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9
   \\
 2 & \{1,4\} & \{3,6\} &
   \{2,8\} & 182 & \{6,12\} &
   28 & \{24,48\} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
I've also explored cycle graphs instead of path graphs.
For a cycle graph of $n=6$ nodes, the process falls into cycles of
length $2$ or $6$. For $n=8$, the cycle length is $1$—all zeros.

---

[image: Cyc6]

          

<sup>Iteration falls into a cycle of length $2$.</sup>

---

The process may be similarly defined on any graph.
I've made some preliminary explorations without seeing a clear pattern.

---

Replying to Moritz Firsching's question in a comment,
a cycle of length $6$ for $n=7$:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 4 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 5 & 3 & 5 & 0 & 2 & 4 & 2 \\
 3 & 3 & 3 & 0 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\
 3 & 6 & 3 & 0 & 4 & 1 & 4 \\
 6 & 6 & 6 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 6 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
 5 & 5 & 5 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
 5 & 3 & 5 & 0 & 2 & 4 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: Note that the operation is that of multiplying by the adjacency matrix mod $n$, so multiple steps are multiplication by powers of the adjacency mod $n$.

Comment: What is the permutation that gives a cycle length of $6$ for $n=7$?

Comment: I see, so the original permutation does not need to be part of the cycle.

Comment: @MoritzFirsching: Right, I  just start with a random permutation, and then await a cycle.

Comment: This reminds me (for odd n) of additive permutations.  I will look for connections and report back.  Gerhard "Going On A Combinatorial Path" Paseman, 2017.08.26.

Comment: Have you done an exhaustive search? Or used symmetry to do a comprehensive search?  I suspect this anomaly may be related to the automorphism group of Alt(6).  Gerhard "Number Six Is Exceedingly Symmetric" Paseman, 2017.08.26.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: Will do an exhaustive search later...

Comment: OK. I will edit your post to indicate that your results are not yet exhaustive.  Gerhard "To Make A Good Impression" Paseman, 2017.08.26.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: Exhaustive search verified the cycles displayed up to $n=7$. In particular, for $n=6$, there is just the one cycle of length $182$.

Comment: I have been agonizing over whether to mention this at all, since it is *so* tangential, yet let me say that this reminds me of an interesting niche-subject within flow-theory of graphs: *zero-sum flows*, about which you can find much by searching. Roughly, these are flow-like-assignments to the *edges*, the flow-condition being defined *without an orientation on the edges*. This is quite different from classic flows on graphs, and I think that this will not help you much, yet it *is* a subject where weights are being added at each vertex (and modulo a fixed modulus).

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: Also verified $n=8$, but I will stop there. Re-edited to reflect this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: for $n=10$, and the identity permutation, the process takes 48422 step until it cycles. In fact, taking powers of the adjacency matrix mod $n$ until *it* becomes cyclic, you need to take this many steps:
$1, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 182, 12, 28, 48, 48422, 20, 1638, 24, 1200, 6240, 120, 32,...$.
(not (yet) in OEIS). For the even cases, like 6, you seem to get back to the identity.

Comment: @MoritzFirsching: $48422$ is impressive! Yes, I've tried to find various derived sequences in the OEIS without luck.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke, the sequence continues like $30172506, 36, 7812, 4067052$ for $n=18, 19, 20, 21$. It seems in general numbers with small factors give larger values.

Comment: @MoritzFirsching: Your computational abilities (& processors) $\gg$ mine. :-)

Comment: $182=2\cdot7\cdot13$, $7\equiv13\equiv1\bmod6$; $48422=2\cdot11\cdot31\cdot71$, $11\equiv31\equiv71\equiv1\bmod{10}$.

Comment: Let p be an odd prime, and let A be (the matrix representing) left shift drop (introducing a zero) of a vector of length p, and B be right shift. So A^p = B^p = O and ABA=A and BAB=B The data by Moritz Firsching suggest (A+B)^(2p-1) = A+B mod p. Can this be proved?  Gerhard "Calling All Combinatorialists And Matricians" Paseman, 2017.08.26.

Comment: Similarly for powers pp of 2 I am seeing (pp-1)pp/2 in the sequence, and maybe (pp-1)phi(pp) for prime powers in general. Can this be proven or at least numerically confirmed?  Gerhard "This Who Can't Prove, Conjecture" Paseman, 2017.08.26.

Comment: While the *explanatory value of*, or even *explainability of* cellular automata is notoriously controversial (though they are certainly wonderful things), I think it is a relevant comment that your discovery is strongly reminiscent of what is ill-advisedly called an [elementary cellular automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_cellular_automaton). Why 'ill-advised'? Because the modifier 'elementary', added to 'cellular automaton', does not correspond to how the modifier 'elementary' is used in modern mathematics (namely, to indicate first-order logic, not dimensionality).

Answer (score 3):

Too long for a comment.

Let $$A=\left(\begin{array}{rrrrrr}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right)$$ be the adjacency matrix of the path graph for $n=6$. The characteristic polynomial of $A^k$ evaluated at $1$ gives the following for $0\leq k\leq 182$ (we take everything over the ring $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$):
$$[0,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 5, 1, 5, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 2, 1, 5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 5, 4, 1, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 4, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 4, 1, 1, 5, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 4, 5, 1, 5, 3, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 4, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 5, 4, 5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 0]$$The smallest $k$ where this happens to be $0$ is the 91st entry in the list. Here the matrix is $$
A^{91} = \left(\begin{array}{rrrrrr}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$
$A^{182}$ is the identity.

Unfortunately, not even the reasoning $\chi(A^k)(1)\neq0$ implies there is no $w$, such that $Aw=w$ seems to apply in the $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ situation; for example we have $$A^7\cdot (3,3,3,3,3,3)^t = (3,3,3,3,3,3)^t$$

Comment: Wonderful!! Does any reasoning suggest itself beyond "this happens to be"?

Comment: I missed a zero at entry 91, there needs to be some more reasoning...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a dumb conjectural answer to Joseph's question: there is only one cycle (of length 182) in the transition graph for the space involving a path of length 6 with a starting point of a permuted labelling of the variables.

More generally, we can consider a set V of labelled graphs v, and a directed edge (v,w) if T(v)=w, where (as Brendan McKay commented) T is modular matrix multiplication on the vertex vector of v under a standard system of notation. For simplicity, consider V as composed of an initial set of labelled graphs P union T(P), T(T(P)), and further iterated.  Since P and the nature of T is bounded, it is unsurprising that V is finite and contains cycles.

If we choose P to be the set of all mod 6 labelling of a path of length 6, we should find some other cycle lengths as well.  There may be some numeric invariants describing T^k(P), which I will investigate and report back here with results.  The literature Peter Heinig mentioned may be more relevant than he states. I am looking for connections to additive permutations (link to MathOverflow question forthcoming).

I have not calculated V for anything above n=3 yet, so at this time remember the first sentence, however likely it at seem, is conjectural.

Gerhard "Taking Small Steps Towards Theorems" Paseman, 2017.08.26.

Comment: Actually, I have now verified that "there is only one cycle (of length $182$) in the transition graph for the space involving a path of length $6$ with a starting point of a permuted labeling of the variables."

Comment: Of course, the graph could be a disjoint union of connected graphs each with a single cycle (If I ignore Joseph's comment above).  I will say more after some hand computation.  Gerhard "Not Ready For Foot Computation" Paseman, 2017.08.26.

Answer (score 1):

Here is more data for small cases, with a suggestion that someone who knows representation theory and combinatorics might be able to give a general answer and explain some of the numbers Joseph and Moritz are computing.

For the n=2 case, the dynamic takes (a b) to (b a), so the general state space and it's transition graph are easily computed and understood.  For n=3, we get (a,b,c) goes to (b,a+c,b). (Here and below, assume + is addition modulo the appropriate number, usually n.) If we iterate this dynamic twice, we get two pieces stitched together , (.b.) goes to (.-b.) and (a.c) goes to (a+c.a+c). Thus repeating the operation twice on a path shows a pair of dynamics in tandem, and we can analyze each separately. Or, we can look at it as a long cycle if we just want to analyze the period, as in (a.c) goes to (.a+c.) goes to (a+c.a+c).  Here it is not hard to show the dynamic repeats with a period dividing 4, and one can look at fixed points to find what period lengths actually occur.

For n=4, (half of) the dynamic becomes (a.c.) goes to (.a+c.c) goes to (a+c.a+2c.), and a string reversal version occurs for the other half.  Note the Fibonacci like pattern that occurs, which when iterated 4 times becomes (2a+3c.3a+5c.) and 6 times (5a+8c.8a+13c.)=(a.c.) mod 4. So for n=4  periods must divide 6.

For n=5 we have (a.c.e) to (.a+c.c+e.) to (a+c.a+2c+e.c+e) to (.2a+3c+e.a+3c+2e.) to (2a+3c+e.3a+6c+3e.a+3c+2e) to (mod 5) (.-c-e.-a-c.), so we see a cycle of length 8 about to occur.

I haven't computed fully for n=6 yet, but following the pattern acting on (a.c.e.) suggests a transition matrix  of [[2 1 0],[1 2 1],[0 1 1]] for the square of half the dynamic, and a similar but not identical matrix for the square of the other disjoint half.  I suspect mod 6 these matrices will have a period of 91.

Gerhard "Not Ready For Prime Time" Paseman, 2017.08.26.

Comment: An oddity of interest: mod 6, the three by three matrix has fifth power equal to -1 -1 0 -1 -1 -1 0 -1 0.  Gerhard "Too Tired For Square Brackets" Paseman, 2017.08.26.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>I do not consider the following an answer, most especially since I take you main question to be very focused one: to mathematically explain the 182. Yet I think pointing out the relevance to what is called 'totalistic cellular automata' is on-topic. The comment boxes are too small to appropriately do so.</sub>

The most relevant technical terms related to your question known to me are 'totalistic cellular automaton' and 'isotropic rules', as in e.g.

[image: Emmanual Sapin, Olivier Bailleux, Jean-Jacques Chabrier: Research of a Cellular Automaton Simulating Logic Gates by Evolutionary Algorithms; in the proceedings of 'Genetic Programming: 6th European Conference']
The most relevant published article known to me is

[Carsten Marr, Marc-Thorsten Hütte: *Outer-totalistic cellular automata on graphs*. Physics Letters A 373 (2009) 546-549](http://sysbio.jacobs-university.de/website/sites/default/files/reprints/marr09.pdf)

The definitions therein do *not* really meet your needs though. This already begins with 'states' being only allowed to be elements of $2$ in loc. cit. I also cursorily checked whether some of your numbers show up in    loc. cit., without finding any. Yet I think you might make progress by looking into this part of the literature, or contacting the authors of loc. cit.

Also very relevant (especially since it allows *integer valued states*, yet again not answering your question, is [Dan Gordon: *On the Computational Power of Totalistic Cellular Automata*. Mathematical Systems Theory. 20, 43-52 (1987)](http://cs.haifa.ac.il/~gordon/totalistic.pdf).

Again, there are the expected slight mismatches, notably that loc.cit. *includes the value of a cell whose next state is to be computed into the sum which determines the next state*. And philosophically, loc. cit. contains results which are sadly rather discouraging when it comes to *mathematically explaining* you discovery (where 'mathematically explaining' here means 're-generating your empirical discoveries from the traditional logical primitives of modern mathematics', which would be the most desirable outcome), since it contains results of *computational universality*.

And yet again, loc. cit.seems very close and contacting the author of loc. cit. seems a good thing to try.

**Edit:** I think your discovery fits into an existing *terminological framework* (though this does not give much of an *explanation*):

- the iteration you defined is an $n$-color [totalistic cellular automaton](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotalisticCellularAutomaton.html) with, however, *non-periodic boundary conditions*.

**Remarks.**

- Note that your rule that the vertex-to-be-updated does *not* contribute its current value to the sum which determines its next state can be 'simulated'/'is an instance of' the definition of 'totalistic cellular automaton' on [this website](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotalisticCellularAutomaton.html). 
  I am only speaking about your question for *paths*; and I take it that you are working over the ring $\mathbb{Z}/(n)$, where $(n)$ denotes the principal ideal generated by $n$.

I assume you are working with the path graph $0\text{-}1\text{-}\dotsm\text{-}n-1$.

I write $v_i^{t}$ for the value of vertex $i$ at time $t$.

For $0<i<n-1$ you require<sup>1</sup>

$\mathbf{v_{i}^{t+1} + (n)} = v_{i-1}^{t}+v_{i+1}^{t} + (n)$ ${}\qquad\qquad$ (global.rule)

At the boundaries you require (which is a serious complication when it comes to making a precise connection with the existing literature on cellular automata)

$\mathbf{v_{0}^{t+1} + (n)} = v_{1}^{t} + (n)$  ${}\qquad\qquad$(left.boundary.rule)

$\mathbf{v_{n-1}^{t+1} + (n)} = v_{n-2}^{t} + (n)$ 
${}\qquad\qquad$(right.boundary.rule)

Now the point I would like to make is that your (global.rule) just **is** one of the hundreds upon hundreds of rules known and documented by Wolfram. I did not try to find out which decimal number they have assigned to your rule. Nor did I try to find out whether Wolfram has a classification for rules which suddenly change at the boundaries (such as yours do). Let me just mention that this violates what

Carsten Marr, Marc-Thorsten Hütte: Outer-totalistic cellular automata on graphs. Physics Letters A 373 (2009) 546-549

in Section 2 call 'Homogeneity'.

Let me also mention that looking into [K.
 Salman: ANALYSIS OF ELEMENTARY CELLULAR AUTOMATA
BOUNDARY CONDITIONS](http://airccse.org/journal/jcsit/5413ijcsit03.pdf),

and contacting the author, seems a relevant thing to try.

<sup>1</sup>  <sub>I use the boldface for readability only; it is not inteded to have mathematical meaning.</sub>